# Rspec before_destroy callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Callbacks:

```
  before_destroy :cannot_destroy_if_has_consent_form

  def cannot_destroy_if_has_consent_form
    if self.consent_forms.any?
      errors.add(:base, 'Language is associated with consent form and cannot be deleted')
      false
    end
  end
```

RSpec:

```
 describe "callbacks" do
    it "#cannot_destroy_if_has_consent_form" do
      cl1 = create(:consent_language)
      test_delete(cl1)
      cl2 = create(:consent_language, :active)
      cf = create(:consent_form)
      expect{(test_cannot_delete.cl2).to be_truthy}
    end
  end
```

How to write RSpec test? I started but I don't know how, allways pass test but is it wrong?

Comment: Just as a side note, if consent_forms is a model relation, you can get similar functionality very easily using the relation `dependent:` option on the relation, like so: `has_many :consent_forms, dependent: :restrict_with_error`. This will stop the deletion of the parent if children exist, and add an error message to the model for you automatically.

Comment: Thank you John! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about your model names and associations, but assuming your `ConsentLanguage` has_many `consent_forms` and `ConsentForm` belongs_to `consent_language`:

```
describe "callbacks" do
  it "#cannot_destroy_if_has_consent_form" do
    consent_language = create(:consent_language)
    create(:consent_form, consent_language: consent_language)
    expect { consent_language.destroy }.to_not change(ConsentLanguage, :count)
  end
end
```

Comment: test pass :) yeah,those are associations i think this is good :)

Comment: i have more callbacks to test, can you help me? Thanks for this callback :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect the consent_form child to the consent_language parent.

```
cf = create(:consent_form, :consent_language => cl2)
```

Otherwise, the relationship isn't set up, and your `cf` is being attached to a different consent_language.

Comment: ok, and what should be in expect?test_cannot_delete is a helper method
can you write exactly what should look like test?